# Calculate the difference and sum of two times and round to the nearest 1/4 hour in decimal format

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, rounding

I am trying to create a simple spreadsheet to accurately calculate the difference between two times, over three separate periods in a day for staff payroll purposes. There is a start and end time for each input to the exact minute in 24 hour time (07:21, 22:42 etc). There is a total column for each of the three periods which needs to SUM the work time, convert it to decimal, and round to the nearest 1/4 hour (i.e: 4.75 hours) in the one formula.

I can achieve one or the other, but cannot get my formulas to work together for some reason. I have tried INT, ROUND, MINUTE etc based on the following:

```
=((ROUND(C9*96,0)/96)*24)-((ROUND(B9*96,0)/96)*24)

=INT(c9)*24+HOUR(c9)+ROUND(MINUTE(c9)/60,2)-INT(b9)*24+HOUR(b9)+ROUND(MINUTE(b9)/60,2)
```

And several hundred variations.

I think I am overthinking this one, and not using a correct formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MROUND` allows you to round to the nearest multiple (which doesn't have to be an integer).  Date/time values in Excel are stored as fractional numbers of days, so to convert to hours you can just multiply by 24.  Putting those together gives:

```
=MROUND(24*(C9-B9),0.25)
```

Comment: To retain actual time values you could divide the `MROUND` result by 24 or use `=MROUND(A14,TIME(0,15,0))` which does not require conversion.

Comment: @Aucuparia 's solution is exactly what I needed. Thank-you for your prompt reply and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

=ROUND((C9-B9)*96,0)/96*24